# Dnn Extension Verification System Error testing SQL Azure compatability

Tags: dotnetnuke, azure-sql-database, dotnetnuke-module, dotnetnuke-7

I have a custom moduel that I have been developing (in DNN 7.1) and then testing with the EVS (Extension Verification System).  I only have one error left and I am not sure how to trouble shoot it.

Here is the error:

> ExtensionMessageID: 664647
>
> ExtensionID: 60892
>
> MessageTypeID: 1
>
> MessageID: b25d95e3-06d0-4241-9729-96f85cfddcbf
>
> Message: While testing against 07.01.00 01.00.00.sqldataprovider
>   returned an error: Database 'TestSchema' does not exist.
>
> Rule: PackageVerification.Rules.SQLTestRunner

TestSchema is not part of the SqlDatProvider I created.  Also, the Sql data provider I created executes fine on my local SQL server.

Does anyone know where this error is coming from.  It appears that the EVS cannot create the test database it needs to execute the sql scripts.  I wish there was better documentation to the errors/warnings the EVS system generates.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: This would probably be best asked on DNNSoftware.com to reach the developers who maintain EVS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the SQL install scripts DNN requires the use of two tokens `{databaseOwner}` and `{objectQualifier}`. When EVS tests for the correct usage of these tokens, `{databaseOwner}` it replaced with 'TestSchema' and `{objectQualifier}` is replaced with 'TestQualifier'. Your install scripts should never reference a database name, as there is no token to that can be substituted out for the database name. In EVS the database names are auto generated by base64 encoding a GUID and they typically look like this (Ll0YaJ7lDkST9pwjmVubuQ).

Do you have a 'USE' statement or possibly a three part object reference?`(databasename.databaseowner.objectqualifer_objectname)` in that example if you removed the first part and then put in the tokens it would look like this `({databaseOwner}{objectQualifier}objectname)`.

Comment: Thanks Nathan, So I did not have a database name or three part object reference, but I did have an unneeded dot between the objectqualifier and the object name.  Also, I have a constraint declaration that did not contain the objectQualifier.

Answer (score 1):

The typical errors I found when using the EVS test with regard to the Azure script compatibility is when you include the "WITH PRIMARY" storage directive in your CREATE statement.  Make sure to remove these directives as SQL Azure doesn't like them.